# How to make svg path pointed?

Tags: css, svg

```css
.fancybox-layout6 .cshero-fancybox-effect svg path {
    stroke: #da1527;
    fill: #FFF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
}
```

```html
<svg style="fill: #222;" height="60px" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

I have an SVG triangle and I have rotated it to 90deg, I added the stroke, stroke-width but my problem is when I add stroke-line-join, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you missed is `stroke` property. So i added `stroke="black"`. The `stroke-linejoin="round"` you can add it either in SVG itself or CSS. As of now, I added it in CSS

```css
.fancybox-layout6 .cshero-fancybox-effect svg path {
    stroke: #da1527;
    fill: #FFF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
}
```

```html
<svg style="fill: #222;" height="60px" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0" stroke="black"
    ></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi, I already update my code base on your answer but i still wont work
[https://screenshots.firefox.com/WnTKY11NYu6mjiKM/synergymediaprojects.co.uk]

Comment: @MarvynSue but its working on the preview! please share your exact problem code

Comment: "but its working on the preview" Seems unlikely given the CSS selector you are using...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your path goes right to the edges of your SVG.

When you add a stroke width and line joins, they are overflowing the edges of your SVG, and getting cut off.

If we unstretch your SVG, add a blue border to show the boundaries of the SVG, and turn on overflow, it should be clear what is happening.

```css
svg path {
    stroke: #da1527;
    fill: #FFF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
}

svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: dashed 1px blue;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```

To fix that, you will either have to:

1. make your triangle path smaller, so that the stroke joins and caps fit inside your viewBox bounds, or
2. make your `viewBox` bigger, to tak account of the caps and joins.

In the example below I have chosen the "adjust the viewBox" approach.

```css
svg path {
    stroke: #da1527;
    fill: #FFF;
    stroke-width: 8px;
}

svg {
background: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg style="fill: #222;" height="60px" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" viewBox="-4 -5 108 116" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0" stroke-width="0"></path>
</svg>
```